# Invalid initialization of reference : difference between pointer and value?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Considering the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Type> class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(Type* ptr) : _ptr{ptr}, _val{*ptr} {;}
        inline Type*& getptr() {return _ptr;}
        inline Type*& getptrc() const {return _ptr;}
        inline Type& getval() {return _val;}
        inline Type& getvalc() const {return _val;}
    protected:
        Type* _ptr;
        Type _val;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = {0, 1, 2};
    MyClass<const double> x(&v[0]);
    x.getval();
    x.getvalc(); // <- OK
    x.getptr();
    x.getptrc(); // <- ERROR : "invalid initialization of reference of type 'const double*&' from expression of type 'const double* const'"
    return 0;
}
```

GCC produce an error for the getptrc function `invalid initialization of reference of type 'const double*&' from expression of type 'const double* const'`. But the function getvalc compiles well. I do not understand the difference between getvalc and getptrc that is at the origin of the error.

What is the cause of the error and why I can't put a const for a function that returns a reference to a pointer ?

Comment: If you need the reference, here's code that compiles: http://liveworkspace.org/code/8eb059d7b1869316740a6e620ebf5ad2. Of course a reference to a pointer for speed isn't going to do much, and if you need to modify it, `const` isn't the right thing to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const double*&` is a reference to a pointer to a `const double`.

`const double* const` is a **const** pointer to a `const double`.

This means that you have to *return a constant pointer*.

```
inline Type* const & getptrc() const {return _ptr;}
```

`const` on methods means that you will not modify the data member. To fullfill that contract, you have to return a constant pointer because otherwise, you could modify the data member `_ptr`. However, in your other case with `getvalc`, you already have fullfilled that contract by returning a `const double`.

Comment: Oh, how I hate C++ and its syntactic idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 1):

In `MyClass<const double>`, the name `Type` refers to `const double`. So the member function `getvalc()`, which returns a `Type&`, is fine: it returns a `const double&`, and `_val` cannot be modified through that reference.

There's another layer of indirection for `Type*&`; although `Type` is `const double`, the pointer that points to it is modifiable; that's why the compiler is complaining: `_ptr` is const inside the const member function, but the function attempts to return it as a modifiable pointer.